# why following code throwing exception while establish connection mysql to java using data source

Tags: java, datasource

hi  i am using following code for creating connection using datasource but its giving error
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]

This is my code in java class

```
             System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                 "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
             System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
                 "org.apache.naming");     
        Properties  properties = new Properties ();
        properties.setProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        properties.setProperty("maxActive", "10");
        properties.setProperty("maxIdle", "8");
        properties.setProperty("minIdle", "10");
        properties.setProperty("maxWait", "10");
        properties.setProperty("testOnBorrow", "true");
        properties.setProperty("username", "snefouser");
        properties.setProperty("password", "snefouser");
        properties.setProperty("validationQuery", "SELECT 1");
        properties.setProperty("removeAbandoned", "true");
        properties.setProperty("removeAbandonedTimeout", "1");
        properties.setProperty("logAbandoned", "true");

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

   DataSource ds = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(properties);

    ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb", ds);
```

Comment: Would you please provide what and where the exception is?

Comment: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]

Comment: and exception coming at this line
 ic.createSubcontext("java:");

Answer (score 2):

[Refer this link](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1159563). You may get the solution. Which container you are using? you will need to provide

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
             "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
```

accordingly.